# Transistor Isn't Forming the Connection

Tags: arduino, transistors, multiplexer

I have wired the following diagram.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMou7q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My understanding of transistors is relatively poor, and thus I am assuming it has to do with the voltage threshold of the transistor not being met.

I have set both pins in the Diagram to high yet the LED does not turn on; however, when I remove the transistor and simply bridge the gap between the LED and GND the LED does turn on.  I have check the voltage going to the Base of the Pin and it is 4.98V while the collector pin of the transistor is recieving 3.3V (roughly).  Why is the transistor not working?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the 2N3904?  Also remember that in this configuration, while the voltage is related, a BJT is what most would generalize as a current controlled switch. 
http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_4/2.html

Comment: It's actually 2N3906, if that changes anything

Comment: Yes, of course it does. A 2N3906 is a PNP transistor, not the NPN you have shown.

Comment: Yea that makes a massive difference

Comment: So, what difference does it make?

Comment: Is your LED properly biased ? Try switching the legs of the LED.

Comment: Using a PNP in place of an NPN may explain why you apparently measured ~5 volts between base and ground.  With a correctly connected NPN, you should only see about 0.7 volts between base and emitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the emitter of the transistor is not connected to the Arduino ground.  If you see 5 volts between the base and emitter, the transistor is definitely dead!

You also need resistors to limit the current through the LED, and to limit the base current into the transistor.

Comment: How do I determine the value of these resistors and why is this necessary, and yes it is connected to the arduino ground

Comment: The value of the resistor in series with the LED is not critical, but should be somehere around 390 ohms.  The base resistor should be 1 - 2K.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: The voltage across a conducting diode (LED or otherwise) is determined by the composition of the diode - for common LEDs it is about 2 volts.  If you apply a higher voltage to the LED, it will conduct as much current as the supply can provide.  Fortunately, the outputs of a microcontroller cannot provide unlimited current, but the LED will still draw more current than the microcontroller pin is designed to deliver - the series reesistor limits the current to a safe value.  The base-emitter junction on a transistor is also a diode, but its voltage will only be about 0.7 volts.

Comment: The thing is, the way I have it now if I simply connect the LED to GND then the LED lights up, the problem I am having is that the Transistor (2N3906) is not allowing voltage through.  I am measuring 2.5 V across the transistor (collector-emitter) and the base is recieving 4.98 V but It will not bridge the connection.

Comment: The 2N3906 is a PNP transistor.  It needs opposite polarity voltages than the NPN 2N3904.  For a 2N3906, the emitter should be connected to the positive supply, and the base connected through a resistor to a more negative voltage to make the transistor conduct between emitter and collector (collector to a more negative voltage, through the LED and resistor.)